# php include a localhost:portnumber

Tags: php

So basically I have hosted a PHP file in /var/www/html/ on a raspberry pi using Apache2. Then I have a python file in /home/pi/ that starts hosting a html page in the same directory, on a port number of the RPi's IP address, for example, 192.168.0.1:8002, when I run the python file. Is there a way for the PHP file to include the hosted html page? I have tried the following:

```
<?php include("localhost:8002"); ?>
<?php include("192.168.0.1:8002"); ?>
```

None of them works. Note that I cannot include the html page directly, because including the html page directly does not control the GPIO pins of my project.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: PHP doesn't magically know that "localhost" is meant to refer to a **URL**. You need to at least prefix it with `http://`…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `allow_url_include=1` in your `php.ini` then you should be able to just do this:

```
include 'http://192.168.0.1:8002';
```

Note this will actually attempt to execute the page contents as if it were PHP source, which may not be what you want. If you just want to spit out the contents, you can do:

```
echo file_get_contents('http://192.168.0.1:8002');
```

Or:

```
readfile('http://192.168.0.1:8002');
```